# Confluent schema registry with Amazon MSK

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, aws-msk

I'm trying to use the Schema Registry with Amazon MSK (managed Kafka).
Running Schema Registry as docker as follows:

```bash
docker run -e 'SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC=_mySchemas' \
  -e 'SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://my.cluster.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092' \
  -e 'SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=localhost' \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -it confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.0
# Also tried older versions such as 5.1.2, 5.4.0, 6.1.0
```

The server seems to start fine, ending with:

```
[2023-09-13 14:27:49,015] INFO Server started, listening for requests... (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
```

However, when I try to register a test schema (the first curl call from https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry#quickstart-api-usage-examples) - after 60 seconds, I get the following response:

```json
{"error_code":50003,"message":"Error while forwarding register schema request to the leader"}
```

The server log shows multiple levels of stack traces with causes:

```
[2023-09-13 14:39:49,216] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://10.202.47.204:8081/subjects/Kafka-key/versions?normalize=false (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
...
[2023-09-13 14:39:49,242] ERROR Request Failed with exception  (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.RestRequestForwardingException: Error while forwarding register schema request to the leader
...
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryRequestForwardingException: Unexpected error while forwarding the registering schema request to http://10.202.47.204:8081
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.forwardRegisterRequestToLeader(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1183)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:846)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:412)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

The full stack trace is [attached](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/files/12598918/schreg-error.txt).

However, it's obvious Schema Registry **does** successfully communicate with Kafka: it creates the `_mySchemas` topic (which I set just to make it create a new non-default one) and it writes a NOOP message to it (`{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}`).

There's no networking error, so what can be the issue?

Comment: Why not use AWS Glue SR? Try adding `-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://localhost:8081`

Comment: Yeah, this error is caused by defining the listeners incorrectly (such as, not at all, and using the defaults). The network error is in the registry server, not to the Kafka cluster

Comment: To answer your question @StéphaneD.: I would happily use Glue, but some tools such as Debezium don't support it.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion doesn't help. I get the same result.